# How do I request.post() properly in python for auth.gg api

Tags: python, post, request

The Auth.gg Example Api

```
POST /v1 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.auth.gg
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 123

type=register&aid=demo&apikey=demo&secret=demo&username=demo&password=demo&hwid=demo&license=demo&email=demo
```

The code I'm trying to use (I have the demo items filled out)

```
register = "type=register&aid=demo&apikey=demo&secret=demo&username=demo&password=demo&hwid=demo&license=demo&email=demo"
get_auth = requests.post(url, data=raw_data)
pprint(get_auth.json())
```

But this code returns {'message': 'Invalid type', 'result': 'failed'}

How would I format this request.post() according to their Universal Example?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's broken

Look at their docs and see if that helps